# Filtering prime numbers with Enumerator::Lazy (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, generator, lazy-evaluation, enumerator

As an exercise to better understand Ruby Fibers and Enumerators, I wrote a small program to generate the first 10 prime-number palindromes. (I didn't implement a sieve of Eratosthenes or use Ruby's Prime module; I wanted to focus on generators and filters.)

My first version used a **Fiber** to generate primes, and an **Enumerator** to filter for palindromes:

```
module PrimeSeries
  extend self

  def generator
    Fiber.new do
      Fiber.yield(2)
      3.step(by: 2) { |n| Fiber.yield(n) if prime?(n) }
    end
  end

  def prime?(n)
    return false if n < 2
    return false if n > 2 && n.even?

    sqrt = Math.sqrt(n).ceil
    (3..sqrt).step(2).none? { |i| n % i == 0 }
  end
end

module Palindrome
  extend self

  def filter(generator)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      loop do
        n = generator.resume
        yielder.yield(n) if palindrome?(n)
      end
    end
  end

  def palindrome?(n)
    str = n.to_s
    str == str.reverse
  end
end

primes = PrimeSeries.generator
filter = Palindrome.filter(primes)

p filter.take(10)
# => [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191]
```

What I *really* wanted, though, was to ignore trivial one-digit palindromes. In order to call it like this,

```
filter.select { |n| n.to_s.size > 1 }.take(10)
```

I had to change my generator to an Enumerator in order to take advantage of **Enumerator::Lazy**.

```
module PrimeSeries
  # ...
  def generator
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      yielder.yield(2)
      3.step(by: 2) { |n| yielder.yield(n) if prime?(n) }
    end
  end
  # ...
end

module Palindrome
  # changed "generator.resume" to "generator.next"
  # otherwise the same as previous version
end

primes = PrimeSeries.generator
filter = Palindrome.filter(primes).lazy

p filter.select { |n| n.to_s.size > 1 }.take(10).force
# => [11, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, 383]
```

At first, I didn't have `.force` at the end of my call, and I just got a lazy enumerator back (the result of chaining lazy enumerators for primes, filter, select, and take).

While I think I understand the need for it, I can't find any documentation either for the `force` method (seems like it's an alias for `to_a`?) or the cases in which you do or don't have to use it. I'm curious whether there are cases where you *don't* need to call `force` in order to evaluate your final results.